# Парсер HTML кода

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Научите пользоваться парсером. Всем известен сайт [yandex.ru](http://yandex.ru). Я смог написать прогу, которая забирает исходный код этого сайта. Я не могу написать парсер, который берет с этой сайта погоду. Прям с главной страницы. Мне нужны только три символа, например: +25.
Весь исходный код записывается в переменную `NSString *str`.

P.S: Любой желающий может посмотреть исходный код главной страницы яндекса. Так вот он записан в строковую переменную `str`. Вот мне ее надо распартить и получить в другую строковую переменную только символы с погодой.
Нfшел код парсера иходного кода яндекса. Но мало нужного кода

```
NSError * error = nil;
HTMLParser * parser = [[HTMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yandex.ru"] error:&error];    
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    [parser release];
    parser = nil;
    return;
}
HTMLNode * bodyNode = [parser doc]; // получаем родительский элемент

    HTMLNode *mynode = [bodyNode findChildWithAttribute:@"id" matchingName:@"all" allowPartial:TRUE]; // Берем div с id="all"
    NSArray *newsList = [mynode findChildTags:@"li"]; // получаем NSArray HTMLNode элеметнов содержащих li тэги с новостями на главной
    for (HTMLNode *news in newsList) { // Пробегаем по списку тэгов и выводим новости
        NSLog(@"Новость: %@", [news allContents]); // выводим текст из HTMLNode news и всех children
    }

    [parser release]; // освобождаем память
```

Comment: Вы уже создавали тему по поводу парсинга XML, и там были даны адекватные ответы.

Comment: А вообще, как вы достали этот XML? Может вы все-таки HTML выкачали??

Comment: Возможно.Исходный код ведь html-ный?

Comment: Это не конкретный пример.  Конкретный пример содержит конкретную структуру  файла. А вы хотите, чтоб вас из воздуха выдали готовое решение.

Comment: Ну ждите, когда появится желающий разобраться в груде этого HTML. Если не секрет, какое глобальное задание перед вам стоит? А то вас бросает от одного к другому.

Comment: Щас вот стоит задание пользователь вводит адрес сайта.А прога в текстовом поле пишет только погоду

Comment: А скажите мне, на кой черт вам вообще яндекс сдался для погоды? Он же почти наверняка сам берет погоду откуда-то, а даже если нет, ваша задача что, получить прогноз именно с янлекса?

Comment: 2 перехода по ссылкам с главной яндекса и вуаля, "Сведения для службы Яндекс.Погода предоставлены компанией Foreca Ltd. и информационным агентством «Метеоновости» номер лицензии Р/2008/1306/100/Л от 18 июня 2008 года. "

Comment: Какая разница зачем мне погода с Яндекса?Мне все равно откуда они ее берут.Я тупо попросил привести пример парсера на прмере яндекса и определенного тега.Какая разница какие передо мной задачи стоят?какая разница что я уже создал такую тему если на нее не ответил никто с пользой.10 коментариев.пользы-0!

Comment: Вопросы потому что такие, вы неверно задачи ставите. Нафига скачивать большой и сложный в т.ч. для парсинга html (который, кстати, для него и не предназначен в отличие от xml который служит именно для передачи данных), если нужная вам цифра, которая сама туда попадает из другого места и получить ее оттуда скорее всего проще

Comment: Подскажите как взять именно эти цифры именно с яндекса.Я просто пишу приложение под IOS и вот с этим у меня проблемы возникли.

Comment: @aknew, этот код ОПу на форуме дали :-)

Comment: я знаю, уже с неделю его здесь наблюдаю :) Нравится мне, что любой ответ тут же появляется в виде вопроса, даже то, что является стандартной структурой языка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Мне нужны только три символа, например: +25. Весь исходный код записывается в переменную NSString *str.

Как я понял из этой строки, что весь  `HTML` контент просто хранится в переменной `str`, которая является `NSString`. Если я Вас понял правильно, в строке вам нужно осуществить поиск циферки. Если так, то можно набананить категорию, то есть что-то вроде приватного метода к `NSString`: к примеру, имеем `<pogoda>+25</pogoda>`, теперь нам надо просто извлечь значение между тегов:

1. Создаете категорию к `NSString`
2. файл .h

> ```
> -(NSString*)stringBetweenString:(NSString *)start andString:(NSString *)end;
> ```

1. файл .m

   > ```
   > -(NSString*)stringBetweenString:(NSString*)start andString:(NSString*)end {
   > NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:self];
   > [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];
   > [scanner scanUpToString:start intoString:NULL];
   > if ([scanner scanString:start intoString:NULL]) {
   >     NSString* result = nil;
   >     if ([scanner scanUpToString:end
   >         intoString:&result]) {
   >         return result;
   >     }
   > }
   > return nil; 
   > }
   > ```
2. использование

> NSString *query = [theHTML stringBetweenString:@"<pogoda>" andString:@"</pogoda>"];

сколько есть "погод" столько значений и вытащит(использовать в своем классе).

Comment: Если проинспиктировать элемент то вот где находится погода
a class="b-weather__link" href="http://pogoda.yandex.ru/samara/" onmousedown="cp('v11.weather.title',this)">
Погода
<img class="b-weather__icon" title="облачно с прояснениями" alt="облачно с прояснениями" src="http://img.yandex.net/i/wiz6.png "/>
</a>
+22 <-----------------------------------ЗДЕСЬ
</span>

Comment: Объясните пожста для чего создается категория и файлы?Можно это просто в коде прописать?

Comment: С сайта netcoder.ru "Категория используется в случае, если вы хотите добавить поведение к классу без наследования от него. Т.е. категория позволяет расширить класс и добавить новые методы к нему и при этом не требуется исходных текстов класса, так же добавленные методы автоматически становятся доступными всем классам, унаследованным от изменяемого.  Как обычно, вы начинаете с создания пары файлов содержащих интерфейс @interface и реализацию @implementation. 
 Категория имеет свое имя, список методов и имя класса, который она расширяет."

Comment: Когда вы создадите категорию у вас появится два файла .h и .m поэтому я и расписал все так подробно.

Comment: А как вы классы добавляете в проект? New File->Cocoa Touch->Objective-c category дальше дадите имя и укажите что категория к нсстринг. Потом включите в свой класс и используйте как я описал выше.  Sergey4590 а за что я был оштрафован???

Comment: Хз,разве я могу штрафовать?

Comment: Как указать что категория к нстринг?

Comment: вы создали тему тут, тут и смотритте ответ http://hashcode.ru/questions/130844/добавление-категории?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=130893#130893

Answer (score 0):

Пример вот:
[XmlPullParser. Парсим XML](http://startandroid.ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/142-urok-79-xmlpullparser-parsim-xml.html).

Comment: И при чем тут Android????